# How can I extend lvm+xfs with no free partitions

Tags: centos, lvm, xfs

I'm stuck with a centos 7 vm with 1 disk that has 4 primary partitions created... and now I need to add more space:

It currently looks like this - simplified:

```
mount
/dev/mapper/centos-root on / type xfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,noquota)

Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-root  175G   14G  162G   8% /

lsblk
sda               8:0    0  250G  0 disk
├─sda1            8:1    0  500M  0 part /boot
├─sda2            8:2    0 59.5G  0 part
│ └─centos-root 253:0    0  175G  0 lvm  /
├─sda3            8:3    0   60G  0 part
│ └─centos-root 253:0    0  175G  0 lvm  /
└─sda4            8:4    0   80G  0 part
  └─centos-root 253:0    0  175G  0 lvm  /
```

The disk `/dev/sda` has already been extended, with 50gb free and unpartitioned. Normally, I would do one of the following:

- create a new partition with the free space and add it to the `centos-root` LV. Unfortunately, **sda1-4 are all primary partitions**, so I can't actually create any more.
- use `resize2fs` to shrink the filesystem, then `lvreduce` the LV. But this filesystem is xfs, and cannot be reduced.

I also tried to create a new virtual disk `/dev/sdb`, and run the following to clear one of the partitions:

```
pvcreate /dev/sdb
vgextend centos /dev/sdb
pvmove /dev/sda4 /dev/sdb
  /dev/sda4: Moved: 0.00%
  /dev/sda4: Moved: 3.06%
  [kernel panic] ????
```

But this actually crashes the whole VM... and now I'm stuck. How can I clean up at least one of these partitions, or at least add the space I've already extended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you started out with `sda2` as the sole physical volume. Later, you added `sda3`, then `sda4` (I don't understand why you did that, given that your root filesystem only uses 14GB). Now you have a disk `sda` with four partitions but still roughly 50GB free, if I calculate right.

LVM exists for automating storage space management and making it more flexible. You, however, manage the space on `sda` manually and still use LVM. This doesn't make much sense. Instead of adding partitions, you should have given `sda2` the entire remaining space from the onset, then use LVM to manage that space.

I don't know what `/dev/sdb` is and why your system crashes during the `pvmove`. I am not sure in what state your volume group is right now. Assuming it is still OK, I would simply extend `sda4`. With the right version of `parted`, this is a simple command `resizepart`. See [Red Hat's blog entry on parted](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/partitions-parted).

Unfortunately, some versions of Centos 7 include a limited `parted` that doesn't have `resizepart`. If that is your case, try to update `parted`, or use `fdisk` to remove then recreate the partition. Or use the [gparted Live DVD](https://gparted.org/livecd.php).

If you use the above Live DVD, I think you are done, since it also deals with LVM and filesystems. If not, `pvresize /dev/sda4` is needed to inform LVM about the new size.

Ideally, you should combine the three PVs on `sda` into one, but that requires copying data around, for example with `pvmove`. Which fails in your case, for reasons I don't understand.

Comment: yep, an unfortunate situation. this vm requires 150-200gb of cache space. I found some similar issues online pointing to a weird kernel bug that was never fixed. `parted` + `resizepart`, `pvresize`, and `xfs_growfs` were what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

This article helped me install extra ssd drive and add it using LVM.

The article is in the Fedora Magazine, Same stable as CentOS.

[Add storage to your Fedora system with LVM](https://fedoramagazine.org/add-storage-to-your-fedora-system-with-lvm/)